# Generalisation of the Symmetric Group

Tags: group-theory, symmetric-groups, group-presentation, braid-groups

For $m\in\mathbb{N}$, consider the group $G_m=\langle s_1,\dots,s_{n-1}\rangle$ generated by the relations
\begin{align*}
s_i^m&=1\\
s_is_j&=s_js_i &|i-j|>1 \\
s_is_js_i&=s_js_is_j & |i-j|=1
\end{align*}

If $m=1$, $G_m$ is trivial. If $m=2$, $G_m$ is the symmetric group $\mathrm{Sym}_n$. If $m=0$, the first relation is trivial and we get the braid group $B_n$.

Is there a name for this group for general $m$? Does it have any interesting properties (for example, its irreducible representations in the case $m=3$)?

Any comments or references are appreciated!

Comment: Was $s_{n-1}$ what you meant?  Something seems mismatched between “$s_{n-1}$” and "$\text{Sym}_n$”.

Comment: Yes, I mean $\mathrm{Sym}_n$ to be the permutations of the set $\{1,\dots,n\}$ and $s_i$ to be the transposition $(i,i+1)$. Hence $s_{n-1}=(n-1,n)$ is the 'largest' swap you need to generate the relevant symmetric group.

Comment: Those are Coxeter relations. Check the theory: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coxeter_group

Comment: The definition of $G_m$ depends on *both* $m$ and $n$, right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two extremely important classes of groups related to your question: [Artin groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artin%E2%80%93Tits_group) and [Coxeter groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coxeter_group). If $m=0$ we have an Artin group, and if $m=2$ we have a Coxeter group. If $m$ is arbitrary, we get a "Pride group".

Let's introduce these all formally. We can define Artin and Coxeter groups using graphs: Let $\Gamma$ be a simplicial graph with vertex set $\{1, \ldots, n\}$ and with edges $[i, j]$ labelled by natural numbers $p_{i, j}$.

The *Artin group $A_{\Gamma}$* is the group with presentation $\langle x_1, \ldots, x_n\mid (x_ix_j)^{p_{i, j}}=(x_jx_i)^{p_{i, j}}\rangle$. Braid groups are Artin groups.

The *Coxeter group $W_{\Gamma}$* is the group with presentation $\langle x_1, \ldots, x_n\mid x_i^2, (x_ix_j)^{p_{i, j}}=(x_jx_i)^{p_{i, j}}\rangle$, i.e. is a quotient of an Artin group by adding the relations $x^2=1$. Symmetric groups are Coxeter groups.

We can define Pride groups using graphs too, but more data is required. The motivation here is to prove *very* general results, so the definition is deliberately pretty general. In particular, it uses "[free products](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_product)". So, let $\Gamma$ be a simplicial graph with vertex set $\{1, \ldots, n\}$. Associate with each vertex a group $G_i$, and label the edge $[i, j]$ with a set of elements $\mathbf{t}_{i, j}\subset G_i\ast G_j$ (this is our free product - basically $\mathbf{t}_{i, j}$ consists of words $W=u_1v_1\cdots u_kv_k$ where $u_r\in G_i$ and $v_s\in G_j$). Then the *Pride group $P_{\Gamma}$* is the group with relative presentation
$$\langle G_1, \ldots, G_n\mid\mathbf{t}_{i, j}\rangle.$$

Therefore, we see that Artin and Coxeter groups are Pride groups, where the groups $G_i=\langle x_i\rangle$ are infinite cyclic/cyclic of order $2$, respectively, and the set $\mathbf{t}_{i, j}$ consists of the word $(x_ix_j)^{p_{i, j}}(x_jx_i)^{-p_{i, j}}$. In your case, the groups $G_i=\langle x_i\rangle$ are cyclic of order $m$, and you have the same sets of words but with $p_{i, j}\in\{2, 3\}$ according to certain rules.

Pride groups are named after Stephen J. Pride, who introduced them in the article *Groups with presentations in which each defining relator involves exactly two generators.* J. London Math. Soc. (2) 36 (1987), no. 2, 245–256 ([doi](https://doi.org/10.1112/jlms/s2-36.2.245)). A natural question for your groups is whether they have decidable word problem, and this was addressed in a paper of one of Pride's students: Peter Davidson, *The word problem for Pride groups*, Comm. Algebra 42 (2014), no. 4, 1448–1459 ([doi](https://doi.org/10.1080/00927872.2012.731620), [Pure](https://pure.strath.ac.uk/ws/portalfiles/portal/55277480/Davidson_CA_2014_word_problem_for_pride_groups.pdf)). However, the results of Davidson are not be applicable to the groups in the question as the relations $s_is_j=s_js_i$ do not satisfy his "asphericity" condition, but possibly his techniques can be adapted.